# The <b> tag is replaced by '*' character

Tags: emails

While sending out html emails that are configured to use the following template.

```html
<p>Submitted on [webform_submission:created]</p>
<p>Submitted by: [webform_submission:user]</p>
<p>Submitted values are:</p>
[webform_submission:values:html]
```

The actual value returned is the following one.

```
*First Name*
Bobcares
*Last Name*
Developer
*Email*
mail@example.com [1]
*Please let us know how we may help you*
Test

[1] mailto:mail@example.com
```

I would expect it would render as follows.

```html
<pre>
<b>First Name</b>
Bobcares
<b>Last Name</b>
Developer
<b>Email</b>
mail@example.com [1]
<b>Please let us know how we may help you</b>
Test

[1] mailto:mail@example.com
</pre>
```

I have installed the [Mail System](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) and the [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) modules, selected *HTML mails* in the latter module and in Webform.

My guess is that something is converting the HTML mails to plain text in webform, but I am not able to find it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

After one more day of digging, I finally figured it out!

The issue was with the [HTML Mail module](https://www.drupal.org/project/htmlmail), which was supposed to format the emails in HTML format, as the name said, required an Pear library, [Mail Mime](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/html-mail/mail-mime-class) to format HTML mails. It was converting my HTML formatted emails into Plain Text and sending to the SMTP server.

It had nothing to do with Webform module.

I had set the sender and formatter same in the Mail System module, which apparently solved the issue.

Comment: You didn't say you were using the HTML Mail module ...